# Put a leading space to a paragraph using texttt

Tags: spacing, typewriter

This line

```
~~Some~~thing
```

produces two leading spaces before the word 'Some' and the spaces before 'thing'.

However,

```
\texttt{~~Some~~thing}
```

does not produces the first two spaces (but produces the two spaces between the words).

Is there a way to force the leading spaces also when using `\texttt`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please correct the code to show precisely what you're doing?

Comment: Are you using that technique to get indented paragraphs?

Comment: @Sid: Note that typewriter font is mono-spaced. As such, the lengths of the characters (and spaces) are different to the normal (roman) character widths. To see that both actually produce the same spaces (albeit of different lengths), see `\fbox{~~Some~~thing}` and `\fbox{\texttt{~~Some~~thing}}`.

Comment: I can't confirm this. Please provide an example.

Comment: I am unsure about what actually happens to the spaces, but putting a box around it does produce them. So `\mbox{\texttt{~~Some~~thing}}` should work as you expect it. Although the indentation will be larger, because, as Werner has already mentioned, the spaces are larger since texttt is monospaced.

Comment: I have a txt file that I want to convert to Latex preserving spaces. I used ~ to accomplish this, but when I added \texttt (as my TXT file is monospaced), leading spaces got lost. I using \noindent to not have indentation.

Comment: @wh1t3 \mbox worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I'm quite perplexed, because `\texttt{~~Some}` *does* produce two spaces in all my experiments (as it should, because `~` expands to `\leavevmode\nobreak\ `).

Comment: In 2022 with Overleaf and basic `article` class (no special packages added) `\texttt{~~Some}` does not produce the extra spaces in the beginning of the line. `\texttt{Some~~~More}` works - this does have 3 spaces between the words..

Answer (score 8):

As egreg mentions, `\texttt{~~Some}` does produce leading spaces, so perhaps there was some other issue (such as paragraph indentation) messing up your experiment.

However, from the comments it appears that you are adding `\textt` just to include content that you don't want formatted and you want the leading spaces intacct. A simple way to do this is to use the `verbatim` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Some thing
   Some more thing with leading spaces     and more space here
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. `\mbox{\texttt{}}` worked for me.

Comment: Many users don't read comments. There needs to be an Answer block that answers or resolves the question. I am just stating that the comment helped me resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want indented paragraphs, that is either covered by the `babel` package (it implements typographical conventions common to the language in use), or you should look for `parindent` (paragraph formatting in general) to tweak it.

It is *usually* a bad idea to do such each time. The advantage of LaTeX is precisely that you can apply document-wide formatting changes by adjusting parameters, local changes don't allow that. Yes, it is often necessary to reuse (part of) the text in a different setting, e.g. the technical report in a paper formatted to the exacting standards of a journal or in a presentation. And when that rolls around with it's normal "by yesterday" deadline, you'll be happy for all the time "wasted" on this.